# How to change block's template without using phtml file?

Tags: magento2

I want to change block's template without using phtml file, is it possible

Comment: what block's template you want to edit?

Comment: Well, actually, this is a question from an interview that I've had and I wasn't able to answer it. I tried to google it but have not found anything. Hope you help))

Comment: check this https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/xml-manage/#set-the-template-used-by-a-bloc

Comment: The link @waqar-ali mentioned above is talking about "set a template for block by layout" that is not related to the question.
 
In magento 2, the template is saved in phtml file or html file. For me, if the interviewer wants to change block's template which includes html template file, then we can change the template in html file. If not, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You should know in which layout handle file the block is been in use and note the name and over-ride that handle file in your theme or module , and use referenceBlock="block.name" template="newTemplate.phtml" , by this you can over-ride the block , see the below reference code which i am using to change the template file for category page in the store view (frontend)

Create a file in the path = app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.wishlist" template="Vendor_Module::sample.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```